# What do the Arapesh ancestors do when they "pluck back the bramble"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

I'm not sure about the meaning of the phrase "pluck back" in this passage of Margaret Mead's *Sex and Temperament in Three Primitive Societies*.

> The ghosts themselves are residents of the lands, and a man going upon his own inherited land will announce himself, his name and relationship to them, remarking: "It is I, your grandson, of Kanehoibis. I have come to cut some posts for my house. Do not object to my presence, nor to my timber-cutting. **As I return, *pluck back* the brambles from my path, and bend back the branches so that I walk easily**." This he must do even if he goes along on the land that he inherited from his forefathers.

I know the meaning of *pluck* with regards to plants meaning to pull out/rip.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a difference between _pluck_ and _pluck back_?

Comment: @J.R. I'm asking for the meaning, intuitively, I'd guess it's the opposite of pluck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that brambles have grown from the sides of the path so that they partly cover the path. The word **back** in this sentence means that the frontier, or border, of the brambles should recede as a result of plucking them, so the brambles no longer cover the path. Consequently, the speaker will be able to walk along the path without stepping on brambles.

**Back** in this sense is an adverb meaning motion in the opposite direction from an earlier motion. You can see the same idea in these sentences:

> In the following years, watch the growth of the tree and **trim back** any side branches growing taller than the leader. [[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=r6WBrE0BqQsC&lpg=PA250&dq=%22trim%20back%22&pg=PA250#v=onepage&q=%22trim%20back%22&f=false): *New England Gardener's Handbook* (2012). This sentence also means to cut a plant to remove the parts grown most recently.]
>
> If government and massive firms are to deliver on their promise of secure retirement, they now must shed other programs and public responsibilities. Central bureaucracies must **pare back** or offload other functions to local agencies or lightly regulated markets of nonprofit organizations. [[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=a0U9BwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA6&dq=%22pare%20back%22&pg=PA6#v=onepage&q=%22pare%20back%22&f=false): *Organizing Locally* (2015). The idea here is that central bureaucracies have grown like plants, and must reverse some of that growth by letting other organizations take over some of their responsibilities.]

Comment: Thanks, also the other examples you're mentioned are very useful.